# Python: Any work-arounds for commenting out a line in the middle of line concatenation

Tags: python, syntax, comments, line-continuation

I have this kind of line concatenation:

```py
t = "first long line" +\
    "second long line" +\
    "third long line"
```

Syntax error is raised if the second line is commented out in place with hash `#`

The matter is I don't wish to remove the second line as it may be enabled back on, moving the 2nd line off the concatenation sequence isn't desired too as others in the team and even myself would forget when that 2nd line should be back on and the 3 lines must be in that order.

There's no such `/*...*/` in Python, but any other work-arounds?

Comment: This is an interesting question.

Comment: See this:

https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/slash.html

Comment: @JayPeerachai yeah, using tuple is also a work-around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to use hashtag `#` to comment stuff out while adding, you can do it with a list:

```
t = ["first long line" ,
    #"second long line" ,
    "third long line"]
print(''.join(t))
```

Result:

```
first long linethird long line
```

Comment: yeah i know but the problem is they're long lines

Comment: I don't think you understood his question.
He wants a way to be able to comment off some of these lines without code breaking. Am I write @datdinhquoc?

Comment: yes, they're long lines and supposed to stay in order

Comment: @AmitAmola datdinhquoc I edted mine

Comment: oh, that list is a fine work-around

Comment: @datdinhquoc does it work?

Comment: it works, tks, let's see other work-arounds

Comment: @adirabargil I edited it

Comment: Btw, I was trying it using eval, somewhat like- 

t = '''"first long line" +\
    "second long line" +\
    "third long line"'''

eval(t)

This works but if you push a hashtag inside, there's EOF error.

Comment: @adirabargil i'm asking for work-around, it's a good solution

Comment: @adirabargil Now i did